# Secure boot prevents loading of Windows 8 in Ubuntu 13.04 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop (x64) onto my Windows 8 machine. Ubuntu loads fine however, on the boot menu when I select boot Windows 8 it comes up with a series of errors:

[image]

I also have the error message `KMV disabled by BIOS` when I boot Ubuntu (though that does boot successfully afterwards).

I have heard something about secure UEFI but I do not know what that is really or how t should be disabled (if that is the issue).

My computer is a Lenovo IdeaPadZ500.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two separate issues may be at play here.

1. Your UEFI boot entry for Windows may be incorrectly generated. It is a known issue: [update-grub generates only BIOS based menu entries for Windows, even on UEFI systems](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1024383). There are several ways to fix the problem; follow the quoted thread to see which one you would prefer.
2. Secure Boot prevents Windows 8 from being loaded from Grub2 on dual-boot systems: [Unable to chainload Windows 8 with Secure Boot enabled](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091464).
   See if turning off the Secure Boot in your BIOS menu fixes the problem for you.

Comment: I have disabled secure boot and that has left only to errors “can’t find command ‘drivemap’” and “invalid EFI file path”

Comment: Will the above solution fix it? (or will this tutorial http://www.simplehelp.net/2013/07/10/how-to-fix-the-cant-find-command-drivemap-error-after-installing-ubuntu/)

Comment: @user2521439: yes, this should fix your problem. This is yet another way to solve issue (1).